# JBOSS Bind exception Address already in use: JVM_Bind localhost/127.0.0.1:8080

Tags: jboss

I am trying to start jboss server. I am getting an error message "server already running on localhost".

I clicked on launch a new server anyway.

and i get a bindexception

LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind localhost/127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: I'm not precisely sure what else you could possibly expect. There's ... another server running. Like Highlander, there can only be one (per port). So make sure there isn't another server running, or switch to a different port. Those are your two options.

Comment: How can i be absolutely sure there is no other server running on my machine? I think it is hitting another url localhost/127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: You can be sure after you check running processes to see which ones are holding open the port; this is a lot easier with something like [Process Hacker](http://wj32.org/processhacker/). But both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` refer to the same computer.

Comment: thanks.. issue resolved.. oracle 10 g was holding that port